# Validating form with Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js

How can I validate a form from the view to the model?

I just want to check if e-mail and password contain at least 6 characters. If true, then enable the button, if not, throw a message.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type your email here." />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your password here." />
    <button disabled>Log In</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var User = new Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('form'),
    events: {
        'keyup input[name=email]': 'validationScope'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    validationScope: function() {
        console.log('testing');
        // What to do here?
    }
});

var appView = new AppView();
```

To play, do it [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vhdq4/).

Comment: You might want to consider doing some form of backbone and validation tutorial; this is a pretty broad question that has a ton of different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check to see if the length of the imputed characters is at leas 6.

For example

```
validationScope: function(e) {
        console.log('testing');
        // What to do here?
        var email = e.currentTarget.value;

        this.$el.find('button').prop('disabled', !(email.length >= 6));

    }
```

Or in your case since you want both email and password to have at least 6 characters

```
 events: {
        'keyup input[name=email]': 'validationScope',
        'keyup input[name=password]': 'validationScope'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    validationScope: function() {
        console.log('testing');
        // What to do here?
        var email = this.$el.find('input[name=email]').val();
        var password = this.$el.find('input[name=password]').val();

        var disable = (email.length < 6 || password.length < 6);

        this.$el.find('button').prop('disabled',disable);

    }
```

And here's an update to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vhdq4/4/)

Comment: Isn't more concise if I validate through model?

Comment: You haven't actually shows that you have a model, not all backbone views require a model. Also if your view is tied to a model you would need to update the model's attributes based on the view, this is something that backbone does not do for you automatically (though there are backbone.js plugins that will do that (For example [backbone.stickit](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/))).

Comment: I want to show errors messages. Based on that, isn't necessary a model? And I even don't know the best way to create a model.

Comment: It's not necessary, it depends on what else you are trying to do. What kind of error messages are you talking about? Either way you could use a model which you populate with the data once the button is clicked, but just to enable the button you don't really need to go though the model.

Comment: I'm talking about messages like "Please, at least 6 characters to proceed.". But you're helping me a lot.

Comment: That could also be done directly through the view, for example http://jsfiddle.net/Vhdq4/4/

Comment: But it turns into a problem when I have to validate user's email multiple times, right? How to deal with that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46444/discussion-between-jack-and-guilherme-oderdenge)